# i have warnings while running Android emulator-android studio 3.6.3

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-virtual-device, virtual-device-manager

i have installed Android studio 3.6.3 and installed Pie in SDK manager and then created Virtual device in AVD. 
All done successful.
when i try to run the emulator i am getting error as shown in the attached image.

please try to help me out.

struck with this stage

[image]

Comment: check the below answer it will help you

Answer (score 1):

Android encryption unsuccessful error can show up due to various issues in your device or its software but we cannot pinpoint a single reason.Corrupted and clogged cache is also one of the main reasons for Android encryption unsuccessful error. Such an error cannot get phone encrypt state, which means that encryption unsuccessful error forces your device not to encrypt normally and thus, causes an obstruction in using it. Even when you reboot your phone several times, the encryption unsuccessful message shows up every time.

How to resolve it

Wiping data in Android Virtual Device Manager helped me in my case.

**Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager -> Actions** (triangle down) -> **Wipe Data**
[image: img]

Comment: i solved "Detected ADB warning" by updating Android SDK Build-Tools and Android SDK Platform-Tools.  I am unable to solve GPU Driver Issue.